# In 3D Racing Games, how is place determined?

Tags: c#, 3d, racing

I was following this tutorial: 
https://www.codeproject.com/tips/357063/a-very-simple-car-race-game-in-csharp-and-opengl

Determining place in this game is trivial, as the cars only move in one dimension on a straight line. How would it be done in more generic maps with the cars moving in more than one dimension?

EDIT: 
By place, I mean 1st, 2nd, 3rd place, ad nauseum.

How do you determine which car is closer to finishing than the others?

Answer (score 1):

> In 3D Racing Games, how is place determined?

By that I assume you mean *position*.

If so by a simple *scalar* quanity.

Cars on a 3D race track in a computer or reality,  are still constrained to being on a "road".  Assuming no intersections, you can ignore the third dimension.  Because a track is a loop, you can also *unwind it* and any point on the path can be a scalar value between `0` and `1` with:

- `0` being the start of the track
- `0.5` half-way along; and
- `1` reaching the start again

Comment: Interesting.  Thanks for the input!